# Using archaeological findings for determining weights and measurements

Tags: shiurim-measurements, archaeology

Halacha uses many units of length (amot/cubits), volume (k'zayit/olive), etc. There are multiple opinions regarding how to translate these into modern equivalent units. For instance, the Chazon Ish says an amah/cubit is 56-58 cm, while Rabbi Chayim Na'eh says it is 45-48 cm.

There have been a great deal of archaeological findings in Israel in the last 200 years regarding how Jews lived during the Biblical and post-Biblical periods. Has anyone attempted to apply these findings to determine accurate conversions for these various halachic measurements?

For example, Yisrael Finkelstein, the lead archaeologist in the Shiloh excavations believes he has identified the location of the original Mishkan (Tabernacle) based on excavated foundation stones along a length of approx. 25 meters (about 50 amot, the length of the Mishkan). Has anyone (presumably in the academic world), made a detailed study of such findings in order to weigh in on the relevant halachic debates?

Comment: It's highly unlikely they had that precise a measure back then. They probably just used their arms to say 50 arm lengths and called it a day.

Comment: @DoubleAA in the vision of Yechezkel 40:5 it seems to be implied from the rod of the angel that they had exact measurements for standard amos.

Comment: @trustme not at all. It just implies they kept everything in one project in proportion. Think about it: if the people working different sides had different size arms, you don't end up with a square.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56065/discussion-between-trustmeimarabbi-and-double-aa).

Comment: The Torah repeatedly instructs merchants to maintain fair and consistent measurements for trading purposes. So while they were physically limited to the level of precision they could achieve due to technical constraints (perhaps measuring to the closest 50 grams instead of the closest 10 grams, for instance), they still did make an effort to be consistent. It seems that, at the very least, in matters of trade they attempted to have universally accepted standards...

Answer (score 1):

[Dr. Yehoshua Brand](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A2_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%93) has an essay where he explores the original length(s) of the '*amah*' measurement based on critical analyses of Rabbinic texts and archaeological findings (Klei Zchuchit BeSifrut HaTalmud 221ff.).

Comment: Bibliographic entry from Israel's national library http://beta.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH001856864/NLI

Comment: @ChaimKut Note, your link is not to the book I reference. This [one](http://beta.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH001856874/NLI) is.

Comment: Ah, correct. Klei HaHeres was his magnum opus. Klei Zchuchit was an unfinished work published posthumously.