# Can we use archaeology to determine halacha or mesorah?

Tags: halacha, history, mesorah-tradition, archaeology

Can archaeology be used to determine the proper halacha or mesorah in certain cases? For instance, what if we found a Sefer Torah from the times of Moshe Rabbeinu and it differed from our mesorah. Would we be able to change our Sifrei Torah to match the finding?

On one hand, it would be a Sefer Torah from the times of Moshe Rabbeinu. On the other hand, would we be able to accurately tell whether the scroll was ever kosher? (Maybe it was buried because it was passul).

I think we might have had a question similar or exactly like this on this site already. If someone could find it that would be great.

This question could also be used to answer the great techeiles debate, if you get what I mean.

---

<sup>Related: [If a Mesorah for letter pronunciation is rediscovered, would we have to change our pronunciations?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98361/if-a-mesorah-for-letter-pronunciation-is-rediscovered-would-we-have-to-change-o) and [Using archaeological findings for determining weights and measurements](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81227/using-archaeological-findings-for-determining-weights-and-measurements)</sup>

Comment: Just an example of why this great idea is often problematic https://www.jewishlinknj.com/features/28862-archaeological-evidence-to-the-sephardic-and-ashkenazic-positioning-of-the-mezuzah

Comment: One case of use of archaeology in the rishonim is brought in a footnote [here](https://www.etzion.org.il/he/%D7%9C%D7%93-%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA#_ftn3): they found a tefillin buried in the tomb of Yechezkel and used it as a proof to Rashi's opinion

Comment: The Gemara says explicitly that they found the dead Jews in the desert not decomposed and they wanted to check their Tzitzit to see if Beit Hillel or Beit Shammai was right. It's in an Aggadata, but it's basically _exactly_ your case.

Comment: "would we be able to accurately tell whether the scroll was ever kosher? (Maybe it was buried because it was passul)." That just depends on the circumstances, no? That's not the interesting question. This question here is confusing two things: interpreting archaeological evidence and using archaeological evidence.

Comment: @JoshK why does that show it's problematic? There's no reason to think the writers of the Talmud were unsure what "like carpenters" meant.

Comment: R Avraham ben Harambam in responsum 91 seems to say we would correct our Torahs based on the Torah in the Azara. And regarding Tekhelet, Maharil writes that we can find it again based on the listed signs, if that counts as archaeology

Comment: Consider the idea that according to the Torah, certain items are going to be returned to us via the archeological process, like the staff of Aharon, the Aron Kodesh (which contains the Luchot and possibly an actual sefer Torah written by Moshe), the container of manna and the klal (container of the ashes of the red heifer made by Moshe Rabbeinu). On the most simplistic level, actually having these physical objects will very likely clarify details of halacha and/or mesorah.

Comment: @doubleaa that is Rav Schachters  proof tbat archeology can be used and he mentions that they were upset at those who didn't look to check the tziztis

Comment: "determine" might be a little strong---"confirm" might be closer to what archaeological findings can do.  A couple of examples that come to mind - loads of stone vessels, used for purity reasons have been found, as well as plenty of deliberately broken pottery vessels.  And plenty of mikvahs have been found, conforming to Talmudic/Rabbinic regulations.

Comment: @YaacovDeane- Where in the Torah does it says all that stuff will be dug up?

Comment: @Double AA, quoting Rabbi Jachter, " A second reason for Ashkenazic Jews to maintain their custom is that one should not abandon his tradition even in light of archaeological evidence. One may argue that archaeology possibly can play a role when there is no mesorah, but it cannot uproot one.'

Comment: @joshk circular reasoning much? That doesn't explain why the great idea might be problematic. It just asserts it and doesn't work through any of the evidence. An interesting avenue to research, not an example of anything yet other than one rabbi writing a pop science article (not unexpected for a Jewish link column)